# elastic search select all from equivallent

Tags: elasticsearch

is there any command/function/method, which would allow to select all unique values of the certain field in Elastic Search? Imagine, that such field might have more than 1 value. An example:

```
"education": [
{"title": "Goldey-Beacom College"
},
{"title": "Other University"
}
, ...
,
{"title": "Other University"
}]
```

Comment: This would help you. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html Note that your field would need to be of type `keyword`

Comment: Yes, just did it. Thanks a lot @Kamal. I've faced an error, but found solution quite fast.
Please find my solution in the comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation on the field you are looking about.

Comment: Hi, I just did it and it worked.

Value of iopub.data_rate of 10^7 switched to 10^10 by starting the notebook with the following command: 

jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10